# PostgreSQL JSONB - query condition with variable key names

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb

I have gone through various JSONB tutorials:

- https://blog.codeship.com/unleash-the-power-of-storing-json-in-postgres/
- https://www.wagonhq.com/sql-tutorial/values-from-nested-json
- http://schinckel.net/2014/05/25/querying-json-in-postgres/
- http://stormatics.com/howto-use-json-functionality-in-postgresql/

Consider the following example.

There is a **table** called `plans`. It has the following columns:

1. `id` (integer, auto-incrementing primary key).
2. `name` (string).
3. `structure` (jsonb).

The structure column has a regular JSON object having the following structure:

```
{
  "some_unique_id": {
    "key1": "valueA",   // Fixed key name.
    "key2": "valueB"    // Fixed key name.
  },
  "another_unique_id": {
    "key1": "valueC",   // Fixed key name.
    "key2": "valueB"    // Fixed key name.
  },
  ...                   // can go on up to a 1000 items.
}
```

**Note: The outermost keys are dynamic. They change for every item.**
The values are just regular JSON objects. Nothing special.

I use UUIDs as the keys in the structure so it is easy to lookup and retrieve a specific value, if I know its UUID.

The other option is to make my structure an array of objects (and put the UUID as a value inside every object) like the following:

```
[
  {
    "uuid": "some_unique_id",
    "key1": "valueA",   // Fixed key name.
    "key2": "valueB"    // Fixed key name.
  },
  {
    "uuid": "another_unique_id",
    "key1": "valueC",   // Fixed key name.
    "key2": "valueB"    // Fixed key name.
  },
  ...                   // can go on up to a 1000 items.
]
```

In this latter approach, to retrieve a particular object using its UUID, I would have to loop through the entire array and match the `uuid` key of every object.

So, I chose the first approach.

The table has 3 records. For this question, the value of the `id` and `name` columns are not important.

The actual values of the `structure` column in the 3 records are as below.

Record 1:

```
{
  "bab6246d-802c-4b80-af41-ab15fd1541b4": {
    "name": "Sanskrit",
    "children_uuids": [
      "fa42b4b2-a958-42f1-af33-314e8e1fb6a6",
      "3aeeadfe-6ad4-4229-85a5-5de030c08014"
    ],
    "is_invisible_node": true,
    "tags": [
      "paper",
      "course_paper"
    ],
    "type": "course_paper"
  },
  "dbc33473-8453-4cf9-8ecf-d8013283b0d8": {
    "name": "French",
    "children_uuids": [
      "4bf65ff9-3b11-42d5-a744-adcd1fd5a953"
    ],
    "is_invisible_node": true,
    "tags": [
      "paper",
      "course_paper"
    ],
    "type": "course_paper"
  }
}
```

Record 2:

```
{
  "ed6164d0-fdc0-4259-90a5-fd60d9d716dc": {
    "name": "Pen and Paper Assessment 1",
    "children_uuids": [

    ],
    "is_invisible_node": false,
    "tags": [
      "paper",
      "assessment"
    ],
    "type": "assessment"
  },
  "059d0116-bca2-49f1-b333-58c4dbec8566": {
    "name": "Content",
    "children_uuids": [

    ],
    "is_invisible_node": false,
    "tags": [
      "paper",
      "assessment"
    ],
    "type": "assessment"
  }
}
```

Record 3:

```
{
  "63619c7f-fa73-49af-9df5-4be1eb38cee5": {
    "name": "Q12",
    "children_uuids": [

    ],
    "is_invisible_node": true,
    "tags": [
      "paper",
      "regular_paper"
    ],
    "type": "regular_paper"
  },
  "56eed164-17f7-48e9-b3ce-b5b469e8cb0e": {
    "name": "Q13",
     "children_uuids": [

    ],
    "is_invisible_node": false,
    "tags": [
      "paper",
      "regular_paper"
    ],
    "type": "regular_paper"
  },
  "69d202c1-5c23-412f-860d-1a5d705c31b3": {
    "name": "Q14",
    "children_uuids": [

    ],
    "is_invisible_node": false,
    "tags": [
      "paper",
      "regular_paper"
    ],
    "type": "regular_paper"
  }
}
```

Now, how do I write queries to do the following two things?

- I want to get all *records* which contain any objects with the `is_invisible_node` property set to true.
- I want to get all *objects* which contain `regular_paper` as one of its `tags`.

Thank you for reading this far! Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> I want to get all records which contain any objects with the is_invisible_node property set to true.

Use `jsonb_each()` to retrieve objects on the second level:

```
select id, uuid.key uuid
from 
    plans, 
    jsonb_each(structure) uuid
where (value->>'is_invisible_node')::boolean;

 id |                 uuid                 
----+--------------------------------------
  1 | bab6246d-802c-4b80-af41-ab15fd1541b4
  1 | dbc33473-8453-4cf9-8ecf-d8013283b0d8
  3 | 63619c7f-fa73-49af-9df5-4be1eb38cee5
(3 rows)
```

or

```
select distinct id
from 
    plans, 
    jsonb_each(structure) uuid
where (value->>'is_invisible_node')::boolean;

 id 
----
  1
  3
(2 rows)
```

> I want to get all objects which contain regular_paper as one of its tags.

The json object `tags` is an array, so unnest it with `jsonb_array_elements_text()`:

```
select uuid.key uuid
from 
    plans, 
    jsonb_each(structure) uuid,
    jsonb_array_elements_text(value->'tags') tag
where tag = 'regular_paper';

                 uuid                 
--------------------------------------
 56eed164-17f7-48e9-b3ce-b5b469e8cb0e
 63619c7f-fa73-49af-9df5-4be1eb38cee5
 69d202c1-5c23-412f-860d-1a5d705c31b3
(3 rows)
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks.

Comment: Just confirming - will these queries use the `jsonb_path_ops` GIN index on the `structure` column? Or does it need the "regular" GIN index? (reference: http://blog.2ndquadrant.com/jsonb-type-performance-postgresql-9-4/)

Comment: @Anjan no, functions like `jsonb_each` or `jsonb_array_elements[_text]` (set returning json functions) cannot use indexes at all. To use indexes, you need to normalize your db structure.

Comment: No, the index will not be used as it supports only @> operator, so it would be helpful e.g. in searching a `uuid`. There is no indeces which could help when using *decomposing* functions like `jsonb_each()`.

Comment: That's a shame. A full table scan for such frequent queries would be wasteful. So, if I use my *second* approach to store my structure (array of objects), is it possible to have queries for both my questions, which would use the index (even regular GIN index, not necessarily jsonb_path_ops)? What would those queries be? I am guessing that for my second question, it just won't be possible.

Comment: Unfortunately, your second approach creates json arrays of nested objects. In short, you can use an index when you can use known path to the object in your query or when you test an existence of top-level object in an array. You should carefully analyse examples from [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-json.html#JSON-INDEXING).

Comment: @klin - if I store an array of objects, for my first question, won't the following query work? `SELECT * FROM "plans" WHERE (structure @> '[{"is_invisible_node": true}]')`. And won't that use the index? The query uses just the `@>` operator.

Comment: Of course, this will work, but you won't know for which particular `uuid` the condition is fulfilled. The condition will concern whole rows. I don't think this is what you want. Or you'll have one array for one `uuid` - this is a solution, but then you don't need arrays ;)

Comment: **But** it may make sense if you use `@>` as a prerequisite (a prior condition) and you'll countinue searching in a resultset.