# Getting JSON field key names in Postgres

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb, postgresql-9.6

I have data which uses JSON as tagged unions, such that a top-level object contains just one child object.  The type of the child object depends on its key-name in the parent, not a separate "tag" field, as would be normal in C structs.

e.g.

```
{"circle":{"radius":10}}
{"square":{"side":10}})
{"rectangle":{"width":10,"height":20}})
```

This works very nicely with JSON Schemas and Protocol Buffers.

I have read: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-json.html

I am struggling with Postgres's JSON functions.  How do I do the SQL equivalent of the following Javascript

```
Object.keys({"circle":{"radius":10}})[0]               (== `"circle")
Object.keys({"square":{"side":10}})[0]                 (== `"square")
Object.keys({"rectangle":{"width":10,"height":20}})[0] (== `"rectangle")
```

with JSONB fields?

Comment: This looks relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38347906/129805

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a `jsonb_object_keys` that you can use which is like its Javascript counterpart. For example:

```
SELECT jsonb_object_keys(json_column)
FROM MyTable
```

This obviously returns a record set. However, if you know that there will only ever be one key in a JSON object then just use this as a sub query if this is required. For example:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE 'cicle' = (
  SELECT jsonb_object_keys(json_column)
  FROM MyTable
)
```

**EDIT**

You could get a scalar value as follows:

```
SELECT json_build_array(jsonb_object_keys(json_column)) -> 0
FROM MyTable
```

Note this is json (i.e. `"circle"`, not `circle`). If you need the text value, use the `->>` operator.

Comment: Is there a way to get the first object key, i.e. turning a record set into a scalar?

Comment: I've edited the answer to put an example of getting a scalar value out

Answer (score 0):

You can use a jsonb_object_keys to get the column keys in jsonb

```
SELECT jsonb_object_keys(json_column)
FROM foo;
```

For example:

```
SELECT distinct jsonb_object_keys(metadata)
FROM department.metadata;
```